# Trying to fix nav menu of grou.ps site

Tags: html, css, api, xhtml, navigation

Hello I am trying to fix the look of this site my original site was this
http://graydaddy.com

but know that I integrated it with the grou.ps community platform the nav menu gets messed up and the image gets moved down by a bit.
I have been looking at it for a while but cant seem to find the error especially because I did not modify at all the div that contains the nav menu

here is the modified
http://www.graydaddy.com

This is probably a dum mistake by my part but thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what your problem is.  Each navigation image is a different height.  And because there are no styles applied to the table cells, the inconsistent image sizes are throwing off the spacing between the horizontal line rows and the image rows.

If it's possible, redo this navigation with an ordered list, and text as HTML text, not image text.  Using images as navigation in the way that your site does, is very bad practice.

If it's not possible, re-create each image to be the same exact height.

*Edit: it just dawned on me, you probably used some sort of online GUI editor to create this navigation, if that's the case, there is not much I can help you with as I am not familiar with the Grou.PS.  But you'll probably have to redo the navigation to be more precise

Thanks

Comment: ok cool I will give it a shot do you know what is causing the right side image to look deformed like that?

Comment: what image is deformed?  everything looks ok to me, well except when I look at the site in IE 9, the "sign me up" button is overlapping the border.  After looking at the, my guess is with the padding applied to the input elements in the cell is the issue.  If you can alter the table at all, declare a width on the table and input fields 10 pixels smaller than the width of the containing div.